# Navigating thru txt file with php, searching and displaying specific content

Tags: php

I have made a simple form with textfields, when i submit a button it wrties all textfield values into a .txt file. Here is an example of the .txt file content:

```
-----------------------------
How much is 1+1
3
4
5
1
-----------------------------
```

The 1st and last line `----` is there to just seperate data. The 1st line after the `----` is the `question` , the before the bottom seperator (1) is the `true answer`, and all the values between `question` and `true answer` are `false answers`.

What i want to do now is echo out the `question` , `false answers` and `true answer` , seperatly:

```
 echo $quesiton;
 print_r ($false_answers); //because it will be an array
 echo $true answer;
```

I think the solution is `strpos` , but i dont know how to use it the way i want it to. Can i do somethinglike this? :

```
 Select 1st line (question) after the 1st seperator
 Select 1st line (true answer) before the 2nd seperator
 Select all values inbetween question and true answer
```

Note that im only showing one example, the .txt file has a lot of these questions seperated with -------.

Are my thoughs correct about using strpos to solve this? Any suggestions?

Edit:
Found some function:

```
$lines = file_get_contents('quiz.txt');
$start = "-----------------------------";
$end = "-----------------------------";

$pattern = sprintf('/%s(.+?)%s/ims',preg_quote($start, '/'), preg_quote($end, '/'));
if (preg_match($pattern, $lines, $matches)) {
    list(, $match) = $matches;
    echo $match;
}
```

I think this might work, not sure yet.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
$file = fopen("test.txt","r");
$response = array();
while(! feof($file)) {
    $response[] = fgets($file);
}
fclose($file);
```

This way you will get response array like:

```
Array(
    [0]=>'--------------',
    [1]=>'How much is 1+1',
    [2]=>'3',
    [3]=>'4',
    [4]=>'2',
    [5]=>'1',
    [6]=>'--------------'
)
```

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question, but can be the start of it.

Comment: Thanks, i think this might be something similar to what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
$lines = file_get_contents('quiz.txt');
$newline = "\n"; //May need to be "\r\n".
$delimiter = "-----------------------------". $newline; 
$question_blocks = explode($delimiter, $lines); 
$questions = array();
foreach ($question_blocks as $qb) {
   $items = explode ($newline, $qb);
   $q['question'] = array_shift($items);  //First item is the question
   $q['true_answer'] = array_pop($items);  //Last item is the true answer
   $q['false_answers'] = $items; //Rest of items are false answers.
   $questions[] = $q;
}
print_r($questions);
```